# What's the worm-like creature that touches Ymir before she turns into a Titan?

Tags: attack-on-titan

In the last episode of the anime of Attack on Titan we see a flashback where Ymir is touched by a worm-like creature before turning into a titan.

[image]

What's is it?
What's the worm-like creature that touches Ymir before she turns into a Titan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is source of Titan Powers. It is shown to have existed for a long time, unchanged by evolution. It probably attached to her spine, and that is why humans turn into titans via spinal fluids. It attaching with Ymir made her the first Founding Titan. It probably does not have any free will of its own, except the will to survive. It makes the successors of the titans strongly inherit the will of the precursor. (The attack titan is the only exception.) Finally, the one who can harness the power of this creature is Ymir, through the coordinates on the order or 'request' of someone.

Comment: does that info appear in the manga?